# pipenv command not found in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pipenv

I have setup a python project using `pipenv` inside `/home/user/code/project` directory.

I have setup `PyCharm` to use local interpreter for the project

[image]

But when I run `pipenv` commands in `PyCharm's console` it gives error as

```
$ pipenv
zsh: command not found: pipenv
```

**How to setup `PyCharm` to use `pipenv` environment set in the project?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanna do this graphically from within Pycharm, open your project, go to `File -> Settings -> Project: <projectname> -> Project Interpreter`.

The green plus icon on the right allows you to search for and install packages in the current environment.
You can choose the current environment from the drop-down list on top. If its a virtual environment the entry will look like:
`Python <version>(<env name>)`
If it says `Python <version>` then that is likely the global environment.

Answer (score 7):

You probably didn't install `pipenv` globally. You need to either do so:

```
sudo -H pip install -U pipenv
```

or ensure that the directory in which you *did* install `pipenv` is in the path that `pycharm` sees.

Comment: If you are using a virtual environment, make sure to install it in that as well as globally.